# asp.net mvc3, knockout.js form submit to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a view displaying a list of users populating from a ViewModel.

```
    function MyUser(data) {
     this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
     this.phone = ko.observable(data.Phone);
     this.Company = ko.observable(data.Company);
     this.SelectedGrowerID = ko.observable(data.SelectedGrowerID);

     this.setSelectedClass = function (item, event) {
        $('#hfGrowerID').val(event.target.id);

      this.SelectedGrowerID = event.target.id;
    };
   }

    function UserListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Load initial state from server, convert it to MyUser instances, then  populate  self.users
    $.getJSON("UserList/GetAllUsers", function (allData) {
    var mappedUsers = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new MyUser(item) });
    self.users(mappedUsers);
    });
```

I have a simple form with list items bound to the Company of each user. Additionally, I have a hidden field into which I save the id of the user when each listitem is clicked.

```
        <form action="UserList/Save" method="post">
          <ul id="UserList" data-bind="foreach: users" data-role="listview">
            <li data-bind="click: setSelectedClass"><a data-bind="attr: {id: Id}">
            <span data-bind="text: Company" /></a></li>
          </ul>

          <input id="hfGrowerID" type="hidden" />
          <input type="hidden" name="users" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(users)" />

          <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
```

In my UserListController, I want to get the value of the hidden field 'hfGrowerID'. The Save function looks like this:

```
     <HttpPost()>
     Public Function Save(<FromJson()> users As IEnumerable(Of MyUserModel),
     hfGrowerID As String) As ActionResult
       'do stuff
       Return View ("Index", users)
     End Function
```

Now, the problem is, hfGrowerID  does not have any value and doing Request.Form("hfGrowerID") returns nothing as well. I verified that hfGrowerID is getting a value after clicking a list item by doing alert and console.log.

How do I get the value of the hidden field that is not part of my ViewModel?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add `selectedGrowerId` to your ViewModel?

If you post the form via AJAX, you wouldn't even need the hidden form field!

I'm guessing that the `setSelectedClass` function, the function called when a user clicks on one of your `<li>` tags, is currently setting the value of the `hfGrowerID` hidden form field?

Instead, have that function set the value of `selectedGrowerId` in your ViewModel, and change the submit button so it is a normal button whose `click` event is bound to a `submitForm` function that posts the necessary data via AJAX.

**UPDATE:** *Response to additional code added to question*

I'm willing to bet that your `this` references are getting you into trouble.

Try changing your `MyUser` function to the following:

```
function MyUser(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    self.phone = ko.observable(data.Phone);
    self.Company = ko.observable(data.Company);
    self.SelectedGrowerID = ko.observable(data.SelectedGrowerID);

    self.setSelectedClass = function (item, event) {
        $('#hfGrowerID').val(event.target.id);
        self.SelectedGrowerID = event.target.id;
    };
}
```

Even though it looks like I simply replaced `this` with `self`, I believe that there's a difference in the meaning of `this` inside the `setSelectedClass` function, compared to the value of `this` outside of that function, buy within the MyUser function.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I tried to follow your path but still not getting the value on the server side. Edited initial post to show what I'm doing to save SelectedGrowerID. What am I missing?